# Connections on the Hodge bundle?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, moduli-spaces, algebraic-curves, vector-bundles

Let $\mathcal{M}_g$ be the moduli space of curves of genus $g$. Consider the holomorphic bundle $\mathcal{H}^k\rightarrow\mathcal{M}_g$ whose fiber over a curve $C\in\mathcal{M}_g$ is the space of holomorphic $k$-differentials $H^0(C,K_C^k)$. This is often called the Hodge bundle.

My question is, **is there a natural (flat or not) connection on $\mathcal{H}^k$?**

Even for $k=1$, I don't find any reference by internet search. We do have a Gauss-Mannin connection on the bundle $E\rightarrow\mathcal{M}_g$ with fibers $E\,\big|_C=H^1(C,\mathbb{C})=H^{1,0}(C)\oplus H^{0,1}(C)=H^0(C,K_C)\oplus H^0(C,K_C)^*$, which however does not preserve the splitting.

Comment: What do you mean by "connection".  If you consider $\mathcal{M}_g$ as a complex orbifold with the "classical topology", then you can just choose a Riemannian metric and you have the associated Levi-Civita connection.  Are you looking for a connection with some particular property?

Comment: Yeah! I am looking for one with some particular property...but since this vector bundle is the daily issue for people working on moduli of curves, I just wanted to know if there is some connection well-known to them, but now it seems not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fourth power of the Hodge bundle is isomorphic to the $E_8$ conformal block bundle at level one, and for that bundle (or rather its projectivization) you have the Hitchin/KZ/WZW connection, which is projectively flat.

Answer (score 3):

There's no flat connection because the Chern classes are nonzero rationally. The Chern classes of the bundles $\mathcal H^k$ were actually discussed just [yesterday](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149252/).

Comment: Just to add one observation: every *holomorphic* connection on a locally free sheaf over a smooth projective variety is automatically flat.  Using the Satake compactification, there are complete curves in $\mathcal{M}_g$ containing a general point.  So the restriction of the connection over such a curve would be flat.  However, the first Chern class of $\mathcal{H}^k$ is a nonzero multiple of $\lambda$, which is nonzero on every complete curve in $\mathcal{M}_g$.  Therefore, there can be no *holomorphic* connection on $\mathcal{H}^k$.

Comment: @Jason, could you give some more explanations on the first sentence, preferably in differential-geometric terms? I can't see it locally..